# Changing the href of an <a> tag before it fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My current problem is that I want to change the href of an  tag before the page loads what it was previously pointing to.

```
<a href = "#oldLink" onclick = "this.href = #newLink"></a>
```

I've tried something like this and it didn't work. I've tried:

```
<a href = "#oldLink" onclick = "changeLink();"></a>
```

in another file:

```
changeLink(){
    $("a").attr("href", "#newLink");
}
```

and this doesn't work, unless you put an alert before the change occurs, and then it does occur as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's my first time posting so apologies if the format isn't correct

Comment: Due respect, this sounds ***seriously*** dodgy. Why not just have the link have its correct value before being clicked? Why do you want to swap out the value the user may have previewed (in the status area, by hovering) rather than using the value you showed them?

Comment: I'm essentially working on a playlist web app, so when you press the random button that scrambles the list, i want the playlist to be focused on the currently playing song, meaning I need to change the link location before it fires.

Comment: In that case, I'd change the `href` at random **before** the user clicks the link. (Such as on page load, or after the previous click [if relevant].)

Comment: The href needs to bring the page to the currently playing song though. Either way the current problem is changing the href and then getting the page to move, what the href changes to comes later :)

Comment: The triggering event (mostly whether it's `click` or something else) is very, very important to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this:

### HTML:

```
<a href = "#oldLink" id="link"></a>
```

### EIDT:

The previous solution will create a recursive loop of event, do like this instead

### JQUERY:

```
$(function () {

$("#link").on("click", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault(); //stop default behaviour

    $(this).attr("href", "#newLink"); // change link href

    window.location.href = "#link2";
  });

});
```

or:

```
$(function () {

$("#link").on("click", function (e) {

    if ($(this).attr('href') === '#oldLink') // check if it is old link
    {

        e.preventDefault(); //stop default behaviour

        $(this).attr("href", "#newLink"); // change link href

        $(this).trigger("click"); // click link programmatically

    }
  });

});
```

### UPDATED:

```
$(function () {

    $("#link").on("click", function (e) {

        if ($(this).attr('href') === '#oldLink') // check if it is old link
        {

            $(this).attr("href", "#newLink"); // change link href

            $(this).trigger("click"); // click link programmatically

            return false;

        }
      });

    });
```

Comment: This will create a loop.

Comment: opps.. yup just recognized that

Comment: Maybe add `if($(this).attr('href') == '#newLink') return;`?

Comment: I just attempted the first solution (edited version) exactly as you described, and the jquery function isn't doing anything when the link is clicked for some reason.

Comment: you want to redirect to that link?

Comment: @Ryan try the bottom solution of my post

Comment: Just tried it, it's the function itself that's not being gone into. I placed an alert at the start to check and nothing popped up.

Comment: The function now works, but the page will only move if e.preventDefault(); is removed from the function

Comment: have you put it in `if` block

Comment: Everything is as typed out in your response. The href now changes to what it should be when clicked, but the page does not move to this position unless clicked again

Comment: it is clicked programmatically via code so it should move to that position

Comment: I think the problem potentially, is that when the programmatical click is fired, the window is still being prevented from moving by the preventDefault call? I don't know if scope is an issue here but could that be it?

Comment: due to if condition second time it will not go in to if block

Comment: I can see that, but is the preventDefault still acting whilst the parent function is still "alive"? Because after the programmatical click, control returns to that part of the function. I only have a basic programming understanding, so apologies if my ideas or explanations seem a bit pedestrian.

Comment: No that is not the case

Comment: Well currently, the page will move to the desired position if I remove the preventDefault call, and have alerts in the code. When I remove the alerts however, the page doesn't move. Do you know of any way to fix this particular issue?

Comment: see edit and also verify that after programmatic click it should not go in if block again

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect a link via JS by something like this

```
changeLink(e){
    window.location = "#newLink";
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You also have to change the way  the OP's calling that: `onclick="changeLink(event);"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do by
HTML

```
<a href = "#oldLink">abc</a>
```

JQuery

```
$('a').attr("href", "some url");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first method was correct. It seems that you've just forgotten to quote the text:

```
<a href = "#oldLink" onclick = "this.href = '#newLink';"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the `href` when the link before the click is processed. Instead, change it **earlier**, either on page load and/or (if the link opens a new window or otherwise doesn't cause a window reload) **after** it's clicked.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/zigap/1)

```
var link = $("#link");

setRandomLink();

link.click(function() {
  // Allow the link to be followed, then update it
  // with a new random value
  setTimeout(setRandomLink, 0);
});

function setRandomLink() {
  link.attr("href", "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}
```

Note how the link always takes the user to where they can see in advance it's taking them, then updates as appropriate.

Comment: This is great but it wouldn't work for what I'm trying to do. I'm randomly organising a list of videos, and then trying to make the page move to where the currently playing video is meaning I have to randomise the videos, then change the href to be where the currently playing video now is, and then move the page to it.

Comment: @Ryan: That seems to fit the description of *"...on page load and/or...after it's clicked..."*

Comment: You seemed to be pushing for a solution that follows the current value of the href attribute and then changing it though, which wouldn't work as a solution for me.

Comment: @Ryan: I'm not pushing it, I'm suggesting it, because it's simple and because it doesn't mislead users. You haven't said **why** it won't work for you.